# Amazon Web Services Fatal Error at Run Time "dyld: library not loaded" Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services

After adding the AWS SDK to my Xcode project (with relevant search paths and an objective-c bridging header) I've begun to experience a fatal error at run time. The following can be seen in the debug console post run time:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AWSAPIGateway.framework/AWSAPIGateway
Referenced from:    /Users/Tom/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/06BB3ED1-2D0D-4130-B459-D8B466C59CC1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/091EA908-B457-4FF2-9857-47A2AF40856B/Annotate.app/Annotate
Reason: image not found
(lldb)
```

Any assistance in solving the issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the AWS Mobile SDK for iOS 2.4.0 and above, they are now dynamic frameworks. You need to add them in the **Embedded Binaries** section under the **General** tab of your target.

You can read the detailed integration steps [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios#frameworks).